# Possible to use pkgsrc with rvm/gem on OS X?

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems

I switched from `fink` to `pkgsrc` for package management on my Mac. But now I'm finding that `gem` installed via `rvm` doesn't seem to play well with `pkgsrc`. For example:

```
$ gem update
Updating installed gems
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Exception)
    Unable to require openssl, install OpenSSL and rebuild ruby (preferred) or use non-HTTPS sources
```

Which is puzzling because:

```
$ which openssl
/usr/pkg/bin/openssl
```

I also get complaints about missing packages `autoconf automake libtool pkg-config libyaml readline libksba openssl`, but I've installed all of them with pkgsrc.

Any idea on moving forward with these two? It seems like `rvm` really wants to use `homebrew`. I"d rather not blow away `pkgsrc` and install `homebrew` since `pkgsrc` works very well for all my other needs. But things don't look promising for `pkgsrc` based on http://rvm.io/rvm/autolibs

Comment: Gave up and swapped out `pkgsrc` for `macports`, which seems to similarly sandbox binaries and leave system directories alone. I did have to reinstall ruby with `rvm reinstall 2.1.3 --disable-binary` to get around some seeming `homebrew` assumptions about library locations in `gem`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what exactly causes the problem. But it looks like you're exposing pkgsrc's binaries via you PATH, so that gem mixes up something like libtool or pkg-config.

Try to remove pkgsrc's bin & sbin directories from you path to make sure that this caused the problem.

After that, you can write a simple wrapper to run binaries from pkgsrc without polluting PATH:

ps:

```
#!/bin/sh -uv

PATH=/usr/pkg/bin:/usr/pkg/sbin:$PATH exec "$@"
```

Then if you want to run smth from pkgsrc do it this way:

```
$ ps <your command>
```

Also, I have to say, that is not the problem of pkgsrc, but rather fink's one. Pkgsrc doesn't try to run binaries from your PATH, but uses full paths instead and usually it doesn't get confused even if your PATH exposes other package system's binaries.